# Mongooe pre/post update hook

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a 'User' schema with a field 'status', I want to track changes over this field, so, when the user changes the status field to 'locked', a job is executed.

Which is the way to do it with mongoose?.

I am expecting to listen to an update change in 'status' filed, if the status updated to 'locked', I would like to call a third party API to block a user from the application

**I tried the following**

```
const usersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  status: {type: String, default: 'active', required: true, enum: ['active', 'locked']},
}, {timestamps: {createdAt: 'createdDate', updatedAt: 'modifedDate'}});

usersSchema.pre('updateOne', function(next) {
  console.log('pre save');
  if (this.getUpdate().status) {
    // Run job ie call an third pary api to block the user from the application 
    console.log('do a job');
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just do this in the routes where user.status is updated?

Comment: I want to know any better approach other than checking it in routes..

Comment: As far as doing it in the db level is concerned, what you've tried is the way to go. Are you having any errors?